# Disable or Bypass Session and Authentication in Play Silhouette framework

Tags: playframework, silhouette

Currently my application is secured using Silhouette, I don't use any of the fancy social Authentication features. Just simple username/password
The problem:

- I need to open my end points to an external web app, This will allow the web app to Ajax call my play app. This is just for dev and for a very specific use case.

How can I achieve that ? basically allowing the play app to act as an open web service?

Answer (score 0):

After posting this question on the Mohiva Gitter channel i got the following answer, i am sharing it here of the benefit of future users:

Answer by Christian Kaps (@akkie):

> For version 4 you could create your own `BypassAuthenticator` similar
>   to the `DummyAuthenticator`. Then you need an `IdentityService`
>   implementation which returns an dummy identity for the hard-coded
>   `LoginInfo` returned from your `BypassAuthenticator`. This can then be
>   configured with the environment. The problem is that you cannot easily
>   disable the authentication mechanism, because your code may rely on
>   the identity that the `SecuredAction`transports in the request.